# U.S. taxes for last year of residency

Tags: united-states, taxes, f1-student-visa

My situation: I was a student on an F-1 visa in the U.S. during the first half of 2017. I received a salary while being a student. I had been in the U.S. for >5 years, so I was a resident alien for tax purposes. In early July, I had graduated and left the U.S. I received no U.S. income after leaving.

My question: Am I free to choose whether or not to file as a resident for the full year, or do I have to file as dual status? This link https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2016_publink1000222182 makes it sound like my residency is terminated on Dec 31 as a default, and I have to provide a statement to have the residency terminated earlier and file as dual status.

If it is true that I can choose, a follow-up question would be: What choice is most beneficial? Assuming I had income from another country during the rest of 2017, I assume it would be better to file dual status, since otherwise I might get taxed on that additional income. Assuming I had no income at all during the rest of 2017, it seems filing as a resident for the full year is best, since then I think I'm allowed more deductions. Is this correct?

Comment: "Assuming I had income from another country during the rest of 2017, I assume it would be better to file dual status, since otherwise I might get taxed on that additional income." Not necessarily. You would be able to use the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion on that part of the year by applying the Physical Presence Test to the 12 months starting when you leave the US, during which you will be out of the US for at least 330 days. Then you get to exclude $100K of foreign earned income during that period.

Comment: @user102008: I'm a bit confused by the Physical Presence Test in this case -- there hasn't been 12 months since I left, or even 330 days, so does that mean I do not qualify? Certainly, if I wait a few more months I'll reach 330 days, but then the filing deadline will have passed...

Comment: you can get an extension